# Can Draw and Edit mode be enabled at the same time on Leaflet?

Tags: editing, leaflet-draw

Imagine you want to draw several shapes (marker, linestring, polygon) and also edit them after the shape is drawn or whenerver you want having the possibility to continue adding stuff.

at the moment i have to draw everything and then switch to edit mode then switch to draw if i missed something and so on. Are they mutually exclusive?

I know for sure that this is possible with openlayers.

Answer (score 1):

As I got your idea, you should take https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable
and write some handlers. In my workin' experience, I use it everywhere, where need to edit or create new feature.